# Can a function in flutter(Dart) return different data types based on some conditions

Tags: flutter, dart

For example considering the pseudocode

```
getResult(){
    List lst=[1,"5",4];
    String str="five";
    if(condition){
        return lst;
    }
    else{
        return str;
    }
}
```

can something like this be achieved in flutter.

Comment: Did you try for yourself?

Comment: no... because i will need to specify what type it will return before the name of the function so i am confused on which i will indicate either string or list eg: String func(){}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to do something like this in dart/flutter. By the way, your pseudocode will work if you declare a `bool condition;`

example:

```
getResult(){
    List lst=[1,"5",4];
    var str = 1;
    
    if(str.runtimeType == String){
      print(lst[1]);
    } else if(str.runtimeType == int){
      print('${lst[0]}, ${lst[2]}');
    }
  }
```

In this example the output will depend on the type of the variable str. Of course you can also use other types to compare (double, bool)

Comment: can you please show me how the definition of such function will look like in real dart code

Comment: I added it to the answer, take a look.

Comment: your code will print the output .. but i want to get the output and use it in other computation

Comment: you can just replace the print with return

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is yes. You're free to define the function as returning `dynamic` and return any type you want.

Should you do that? Probably not. Look into creating a union type. A union type that is built into Dart is the [`FutureOr`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.3/dart-async/FutureOr-class.html) class which can represent a future or the resolved type. The [Freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#unionssealed-classes) package can help generate union types without too much fuss.